# In Power Query, when duplicating the source query should I duplicate the Transform File folder as well?

Tags: import, analytics, powerquery

My apologies in advance if this question has already been asked, if so I cannot find it.

So, I have this huge data base divided by country where I need to import from each country data base individually and then, in Power Query, append the queries as one.

When I imported the US files, the Power Query automatically generated a Transform File folder with 4 helper queries:

[image]

Then I just duplicated the query US - Sales and named it as UK - Sales pointing it to the UK sales folder:

[image]

[image]

The Transform File folder didn't duplicate, though.

Everything seems to be working just fine right now, however I'd like to know if this could be problem in the near future, because I still have several countries to go. Should I manually import new queries as new connections instead of just duplicating them or it just doesn't matter?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Transform Files Folder` group contains the code that is called to transform a list of files. It is re-usable code. You can see the `Sample File`, which serves as the template for the transform actions.

As long as the file that is arrived at for the `Sample File` has the same structure as the files that you are feeding into the command, then you can use any query with any list of files.

One thing you need to make sure is that the `Sample File` is not removed from your data source. You may want to create a new dummy file just for that purpose, make sure it won't be deleted, and then point the `Sample File` query to pull just that file.

Answer (score 1):

The Transform Helper Queries are special queries that you may edit the queries, but you cannot delete and recreate your own manually. They are automatically created by PQ when combining list of contents and are inherently linked to the parent query.

That said, you cannot replicate them, and must use the `Combine` function provided by PQ to create the helper queries.

You may however, avoid duplicating the queries, instead replicate your steps in the parent query, and use table union to join the list before combining the contents with the same helper queries.

Comment: The Transform Helper Queries are not magic with fairy dust and can absolutely be created  manually. It's just a bunch of M code that Power Query generates as a courtesy, so people don't have to dive into writing their own recursive functions. But stating that they cannot be deleted and recreated is plain wrong.